# Objeto JSON no tiene nombre pero sí parámetros

Tags: json, nodejs

Tengo un problema con un archivo que subo desde un formulario usando node js.

Al momento de subirlo la linea de comandos me regresa todas las características del archivo, pero NO me devuelve el nombre del JSON:

[image: captura de pantalla]

Y sin ese nombre no puedo acceder a su path al querer usarla en otra parte del código.

Estoy intentando subir mi archivo con multer.

Comment: ¿Podrías especificar que quieres decir con "nombre del json"?

Comment: Me refiero a la linea que dice undefined, en vez de ponerme:
{imagename:{
    caracteristicas}
}
Sale undefined.

Comment: Podría tratarse de un array de objetos? ´[{caracteristicas}]´ En ese caso su "clave" sería simplemente su posición en el array.

Comment: Podrías poner la parte del código que utilizas para el fichero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo mucha información sin acceso al código pero viendo el tipo de error es muy probable que el error se encuentre a la hora de parsear el resultado.

En lugar de utilizar `json.stringify` utiliza `json.parse` y ya no tendrás `undefined`

Ese error sucede cuándo se utiliza el `stringify` sobre una cadena que **ya** es un JSON. Cuándo nos encontramos en ese caso utilizamos el `parse`